# Is it possible to connect to Google Cloud Memorystore from another project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-memorystore

I have 2 different projects (Project A and Project B) in the same region (Europe west 2). 
I've created one instance of Memorystore in project A.
So, I'm able to connect to the Memorystore from project A, but I'm also trying to connect to the same Memorystore from project B with no success.

What I'm doing wrong? Is it even possible to connect multiple projects to the same basic Memorystore?

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible. In the official documentation for [Connecting to a Redis instance](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance) it states:

> You can access Redis instances from Compute Engine VM instances,
>   Google Kubernetes Engine clusters, and App Engine flexible environment
>   applications **within the same Google Cloud Platform project**.

Answer (score 2):

We are working on enabling this use case using Shared VPC. We expect to have this available soon.

In your case I'm assuming these are two regular projects with regular VPC networks and not service projects using Shared VPC. Currently there isn't a way to do this with regular VPC.

Comment: Is this use case supported now? I have two App Engine projects (one production, and one for development) that I'd like to share the same Cloud Memorystore and same Serverless VPC Access, since the development project is only lightly used.

Comment: @Gopal any update here? I see the documentation now says it's possible, but the documentation is very light and doesn't give instructions. For my use case, I'd like to share a Redis instance in a App Engine Flexible project with another project that uses Kubernetes. Is that possible? Not clear from the documentation.

Comment: @Gopal, do you have any answer to this? I'm trying to do something related but they are on the same Project, I'm trying to connect 2 different services on different clusters on the same project with no luck, some advice would be appretiated